# How to delete an empty folder in my ftp with ruby Net::FTP?

Tags: ruby, ftp

The method `Net::FTP.delete(filename)` works only for files, not directories, and there are no more delete methods in the documentation.

Not much to add to that.. seems like ruby ftp could be better off with a few more methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands to create and delete directories are different from that of files.

To create a directory, use `mkdir` and to remove one use [`rmdir`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-rmdir).